# Files is not showing hard drives and partitions

Tags: pantheon-files, disk-management

For my Linux installation (Elementary OS), I have split a 500 GB SSD as follows:

- 20 GB root
- 16 GB swap
- 464 GB /home

The problem is, that `Pantheon Files` is only showing a 20 GB root partition as a device and the rest of it is not shown (as you can see).

My question is: **Why is only a 20 GB partition shown as a device?**

[image]

Another issue is, that I have two physical 4 TB drives. I use them under Windows 10. One of them is called "backup", the other one is not show under Elementary!

**Why is Elementary showing me only the "backup" drive??**

This is what the program `disks` is showing me. I expect the same thing from `Pantheon-Files`

[image]

Comment: Files and Disks have different purposes and show different info.You are correct that "File System" is, in reality, just the root partition. For most(?) users these days there is only this partition and it holds everything. Like you I have multiple disks and partitions but have the same behaviour. Basically, anything mounted at boot time (via fstab) is not shown since those can not be unmounted by a regular user. For other partitions, only user mountable types are shown.

Comment: The drive was not showing up, because it was dynamic. I have converted it to basic with easeus. Anyway to 20 GB partition is a elementary bug. It would have to show me a 500GB drive